# How do I delete local Docker images by repository?

Tags: docker

I have a bunch of docker images I want to get rid of and it would be convenient if I could remove them by specifying the repository name as it appears when I run `docker images`. For example if `docker images` returns:

```
REPOSITORY      TAG              IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ui_test         191127_manual    41a7ca9824d6        24 hours ago        1.42GB
ui              git-24fa8d1a     cdd254eff918        24 hours ago        1.44GB
ui              git-31a4b052     9b4740060a62        25 hours ago        1.45GB
ui_test         191122_manual    ba9cb04ce2d8        6 days ago          1.39GB
ui              git-68110e426    f26ef80abc25        6 days ago          1.38GB
```

what command would I use to remove all of the `ui_test` images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass image IDs you want to delete to `docker rmi`:

```
docker rmi $(docker images -q 'ui_test')
```

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#list-images-by-name-and-tag):

> The `docker images` command takes an optional `[REPOSITORY[:TAG]]` argument that restricts the list to images that match the argument. If you specify `REPOSITORYbut` no `TAG`, the `docker images` command lists all images in the given repository.

Comment: This didn't quite work as the default format returned by `images` isn't usable by `rmi`. If you add the quiet flag `-q` then it only returns numeric IDs and that works.